# Error updating PFObject

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfobject

Data from Parse fill table view. When you select a cell turn on a detailed understanding (detailed instructions). There is an update function object (a transition to another controller). The problem is as follows:

When you select a cell with an index of 0 (ie, the first table cell in the list) and further attempt to edit it - an error occurs, the first cell is not updated, and the second. I can not understand what it is connected. And when selecting other cells - objects are updated properly. Can someone faced such problem?

Here's the code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"DATA"];
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

            object [@"Name"] = name.text;
            object [@"Address"] = address.text;
           object [@"Date"] = datePicker.date;

            [object saveInBackground];

        } else {
            NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
            UIAlertView *error = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Oops!" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [error show];
        }
    }];
```

Where objectId - ID of the object. 
name, adress - UITextField

Answer (score 1):

Your query asks for a user with a username, however you don't give a username as the argument, but a user object.

You should perhaps change your code to

```
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
```

Comment: No error is received. Just not the object is updated

Comment: Where do you get the objectId? If you have the objectId, why would you need to `whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];`?

Comment: I shared with another controller. The value true

Comment: removed whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

still does not work